# Being managed out

Tags: software-industry, management, work-environment, career-development, resignation

I accepted a job a few months ago with a large company and it has become apparent that my boss does not like me.  I could try to identify things that I have done but even at the interview stage I felt like I had a frosty reception. My boss was late to the interview and I was left to stew for nearly 30 mins. The interview did not last long - about 30 mins - it seemed like a rubber stamp exercise and the offer came through quickly.

On joining the company I was thrown into some work though it later transpired this was low priority stuff. Not surprising really but it continued that way and somebody who joined at the same time was given a big project even though he was less senior. He and others who had not been around too much longer had their responsibilities expanded and were given treats for various bits of work. Every project I got the results were rarely used and my boss never talked to me about work or anything else. I made efforts to converse with him at lunch but he largely did not engage and rarely smiled at what I said even when I was funny - he seemed to be trying not to. On completing a more significant amount of work a while ago, it has still not been used and it is now clear it will probably not be needed for months. Colleagues also got invited to company events. I never received emails about that or invitations to informal social gatherings only hearing about it later. In the corridor when walking past my boss he looks the opposite way.

Now it's got to the stage where work has dried up completely and when I asked for something to do all I got was a menial task. The entire time I have been here I have never worked as part of a team unlike others who work in small groups, always alone, always ignored by the boss and on nothing important in stark contrast to others. My colleagues are friendly enough but I've noticed some have distanced themselves from me recently. I know that I openly disagreed with my boss a couple of times about a technical issue and was the odd one out on the team - everybody else agreed with something that I felt was just wrong. I probably struggled to articulate myself effectively as well as I was new and had no support. I feel I burned my bridges and am now being punished/neutralised but I was just sticking to my principles.

So how should I go about repairing my career and avoiding these problems in the future, I am not a good fit for this role and the company is not giving me a soft landing out the door. I have not asked for an exit process either as this seems risky. Everybody here seems to agree not to challenge each other's ideas and just use their own methods, there is no technical leadership it seems.

Comment: Leaving without another job to go to is usually a bad strategy and it will be almost impossible to give it a positive spin when you interview. Probably good idea to take the risk to have as brisk an interview pace as possible as you won't make things too much worse by doing so.

Comment: There is not much to offer here. This is a one-sided story about things going on, with some interpretation mingled in, so we do not know what is happening with your compnay and manager. Speculation about that is useless.

Comment: What would you like, my manager to chime in?

Comment: Hi Spiral, welcome to The Workplace. I put this [on hold](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) to give you time to edit the post; we're not a forum for advice.  As a Q&A site, your post should have a clear question about what type of resolution you're looking for. This ensures answers can be properly evaluated and voted on. Once you edit your post, it gets [bumped back to the top for community review](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult being a person with brutal honesty. We have to learn when and when not to use it. I have had to learn the hard way that unless you have an air of confidence in an opinion that you know to be true, you will be shunned and treated like a fool by fools. It is also quite human for these same people to ostracise you, leaving you in perpetual stigma. It's not a great position to be in. If I were you, I would really work on an exit strategy. The best thing you may be able to do (as it sounds like a fairly large organisation) would be to try your hardest to make at least one ally. You could then try to make them a personal reference from that job. Although the outlook seems to be that you have been axed already - and your manager is waiting for you to make the first move. If they have power over you, but are not affected for having to pay you, I doubt very much you will have any move. Perhaps go on the attack? Good luck.

Comment: I'd love to agree.  Many companies disparage TDD and have horrific code bases too. The smugness lies in not addressing an increasing problem by asserting that business needs rule this out. When time to market is close I accept technical debt is acceptable in the short term but the code cannot be just left to rot because fixing it has no obvious business value. Perhaps I am a fool though, an idealistic idiot.